# Google Cloud Platform of External Taiwan IP

Tags: ip, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

i setted Google Cloud Platform instance of region is asia-east1-a.
but when i add external IP for instance.

When i check location, result always is US.

I wan't set use taiwan IP.

Thanks for help!!

Comment: How do you check the location of IP?

Comment: @DoITInternational i check by https://www.iplocation.net/
with my external IP

Comment: Well, iplocation.net and similar services are only showing you the registration information of the IP, not really the physical location of the device/s managing this address. Run a traceroute and you will see the actual route your packets are taking.

Comment: @DoIT International thanks. But now i need get google play top ranking. But now data return from us. So i thing, ip is realy in us.

Comment: I am having  exactly the same issue where the taiwan  asia-east1 external IP address is nearly the same as the us-east1 and resolves to a US location.  In fact speed tests that I would expect to be faster to Taiwan are actually faster when just going to the US.  It appears that the Taiwan traffic either ends up or routes through the US.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible as all external IP ranges resolve to Mountain View, CA.

Here [1] you can keep track of the public feature request to have IP ranges that match the region.

[1] https://issuetracker.google.com/72263361